# How would I get the values from a previously assigned index

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames, the first column is formed by getting the index values from the other data frame. This is tested and successfully returns 5 entries.

The second line executes but assigns NaN to all rows in "StartPrice" column

```
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df["StartBar"] = df_rs["HighTrendStart"].dropna().index        # Works
    df["StartPrice"] = df_rs["HighTrendStart"].loc[df["StartBar"]] # Assigns Nan's to all rows
```

As pointed out by @YOBEN_S, the indexes do not match.

```
Date
2020-05-01 00:00:00   NaN
2020-05-01 00:15:00   NaN
2020-05-01 00:30:00   NaN
2020-05-01 00:45:00   NaN
2020-05-01 01:00:00   NaN
Freq: 15T, Name: HighTrendStart, dtype: float64
0   2020-05-01 02:30:00
1   2020-05-01 06:30:00
2   2020-05-01 13:45:00
3   2020-05-01 16:15:00
4   2020-05-01 20:00:00
Name: StartBar, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure the `index` did not match when you assign the value from different dataframe

```
df["StartPrice"] = df_rs["HighTrendStart"].loc[df["StartBar"]].to_numpy()
```

For example

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
s=pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6],index=list('abcdef'))
df
Out[190]: 
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
s
Out[191]: 
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4
e    5
f    6
dtype: int64
df['New']=s
df
Out[193]: 
   a  New
0  1  NaN
1  2  NaN
2  3  NaN
3  4  NaN
4  5  NaN
5  6  NaN
```

Comment: This work 100% Thank you, but I am still none the wiser why? Are you able to explain in some detail?

Comment: @Slappy when you do `df_rs["HighTrendStart"].loc[df["StartBar"]]` this carry over the index from `df_rs`, and if you would like to assign it to `df`, df will match assignment index (df_rs index) first , if the index dose not match , the return value will be NaN

Comment: @Slappy also include some example ~